# Reset AutoIncrement from max(column)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to reset my primary key so it doesnt leave "holes" in it.
I found this function:

`ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 0`

That resets the auto_increment column to the start point, so the next field will have "1", if it was

`ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`

The next field would have "2" in it.

I'm trying to make it so the number after `AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` takes the highest value from the column that it is auto_incremented.

`ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = MAX(column)`

but it's telling me it has wrong syntax, can someone give me an advice on how to get it to work?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are creating a problem where none exists.  "Holes" in the primary key are a non-issue.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: yeah i know but it hurts my eyes haha! It's a little school project, nothing so important ^^

Comment: If you are in school, you should be learning how databases and auto-incremented primary keys work.  It is all the more important that you get used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- you can try this, but if it is auto incrmeent how is there records missing from the table for the key?

```
DECLARE @MaxColumn INT

SELECT @MaxColumn = MAX(ID)
FROM TAbleName

ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = @MaxColumn
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Even if it's useless right now that i thinked about it, if i have 4 records this is only "useful" if i delete the last record i got, if i delete the third it will continue from 4 and then 5. Thank you for the help! ^^